# IO Exception -- CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation

Tags: java, exec, ioexception

Why does this `IOException` arise when I do `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String command)`? How can I prevent this?

Comment: "Requires elevation" means you need to have root/administrator privileges to execute this.

Comment: Probably the command you are trying to run needs it.

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Comment: ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder(command);
final Process shell = process.start();                                                  exitValue = shell.exitValue();

Tried this.
Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Same problem here... Can only execute on windows using SWT Program.launch, but that does not allow args!